# How to get count of column 1 on data grouped by column 2 and having latest date in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query where I want to get distinct count to column A which is grouped by Column B but I also want to consider column A count only having latest date in column C in case if Column A data is common in multiple data of Column B.

```
A           |        B        |           C
---------------------------------------------------
101         |        AB       |      2020-01-04
-----------------------------------------------------
101         |        CD       |      2020-07-27
-------------------------------------------------------
102         |        EF       |      2020-05-30
```

Here data should be:

```
A           |         B
----------------------------
1           |        CD
---------------------------
1           |        EF
```

Query should consider data for B  if column A have duplicate values on the basis of date in C column and ignore data for other.
So, in above example CD is considered in grouping Because that has latest data of column and in A column I have shown total distinct count of column so no duplicate value must be included in data of B column

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be describing:

```
select b, count(distinct a)
from (select t.*, max(c) over (partition by b) as max_c
      from t
     ) t
where c = max_c
group by b;
```

I am not sure if you want the `a` value for the maximum of *all* dates or for the maximum of `b` or even perhaps from `a`.  The above takes the maximum date for `b` and the `a` values associated with that.

Comment: You mean partitaion by A.

Comment: @imankazemi . . . The question is not clear on this point.

Answer (score 0):

I hope understand your question well:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (A INT, B VARCHAR(128), C DATE)
INSERT @T VALUES (101, 'AB', '2020-01-04'), 
                 (101, 'CD', '2020-07-27'), 
                 (102, 'EF', '2020-05-30')
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A) A, B
FROM @T T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @T T2 WHERE T1.A = T2.A GROUP BY A HAVING MAX(C) = T1.C)
GROUP BY B
```